# Elassandra Integration with Existing Cassandra Instance

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, elassandra

I'm trying to learn Elassandra and am having an issue configuring it to my current Cassandra instance (I'm learning Cassandra as well).

I downloaded version 3.11.3 of Cassandra to my local computer. I didn't change anything except the `cluster_name` inside of `cassandra.conf`. It runs fine and I used `bin/cqlsh` to create a keyspace and a "user" table with a couple of rows for testing.

I followed the steps on the [Elassandra integration page](http://doc.elassandra.io/en/latest/integration.html). I downloaded version `6.2.3.10` of Elassandra. I replaced the `cassandra.yaml`, `cassandra-rackdc.properties` and `cassandra-topology.properties` in the Elassandra `conf` with the ones from the Cassandra `conf` (I am assuming those last 2 are the "snitch configuration file" mentioned in the instructions but I'm not sure). I stopped my Cassandra instance and then ran the `bin/cassandra -e f` from my Elassandra directory.

When I run `curl -X GET localhost:9200`, the output seems to have my correct cluster name, etc.

However, if I run `bin/cqlsh` from my Elassandra directory and run `describe keyspaces`, the keyspace I created under Cassandra isn't there. I tried copying the `data` directory from Cassandra to Elassandra and that seemed to work, but I feel this can't possibly be the actual solution.

Can someone point me to what I am missing in regards to this configuration? With the steps being listed on the website, I'm sure there must be some dumb thing I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I see, you have installed elassandra as a separate instance, right? I mean, different binaries from cassandra...If this is the case, then the solution of copying the data folder seems right. If you wanted to avoid copying the files maybe you should have [upgraded cassandra to elessandra](http://doc.elassandra.io/en/latest/integration.html#rolling-upgrade-to-elassandra) or [create a new elessandra dc in your existing cassandra cluster](http://doc.elassandra.io/en/latest/integration.html#create-a-new-elassandra-datacenter)

Comment: Hello, you did good. The doc isn't really clear about this, but yes you should either copy or symlink the data folder. In packaged installation, the data location is always /var/lib/cassandra so there wouldn't be this extra step.

Comment: @barth - I tried changing the `data_file_directories` value in my Elassandra's `cassandra.yaml` to point to my existing Cassandra data folder (`/home/myname/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/data`), but the keyspace still isn't there.

Comment: @RachelG. You said that after copying the data folder from cassandra to elassandra, the keyspace appears, right ? That's the normal behavior, and an other way to the same is to symlink (or update data_file_directories) to the cassandra data folder. If then the keyspace does not appear anymore, you probably have a configuration issue.

Comment: @barth - I cannot go with the copying over of the `data` folder. Our company has too much data for this to be effective, so I'm looking at how I can point Elassandra at Cassandra. So I created a standalone Cassandra with a keyspace, table, and sample rows. Then I stopped that and copied over `cassandra.yaml`, `cassandra-rackdc.properties` and `cassandra-topology.properties` into Elassandra as I believe the guide instructs. But the data isn't there, so I tried to update `data_file_directories` in Elassandra, but still no luck.

Comment: I get the feeling I should set an environment variable for `CASSANDRA_HOME` to point to my old Cassandra, but that yields `Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.ElassandraDaemon`.